# Django Template - Looping through Queryset without creating multipletimes Div's

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I except this question to be relatively easy, but since I am new to Django I am struggling.

I got a QuerySet which is given to a template. Basically I want to create a football (soccer) table. But also in general I want to understand the concept.

So for every team in the teams Query set, the data should be filled in the 5 respective columns. At the moment I solved it by adding a for loop into every column. However, I think that it looks ugly and is unefficient. Moreover, I want to edit the id's for the first three loops.

So what I am looking for: A possibility to set the for loop around the div's but without creating the div's in every loop.

Something like:

```
{%for team in teams %}

   <div id="position">team.position</div>
   <div id="name">team.name</div>
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

In addition to adding something like:

```
{% if forloop.counter0 == 0|1|2 %}
  add id/class to div row
{% endif %}
```

Is the smartest way here, adding a variable to the class, meaning class={{xyz}} ?

The template looks at the moment like this.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2" id="position">{% for tea in teams %}{{tea.league_position}}</br>{% endfor %}</div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="name">{% for tea in teams %}{{tea.team_name}}</br>{% endfor %}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="points">{% for tea in teams %}{{tea.league_points}}</br>{% endfor %}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="goals">{% for tea in teams %}{{tea.goals_shot}}</br>{% endfor %}</div>    
            <div class="col-md-2" id="received">{% for tea in teams %}{{tea.goals_received}}</br>{% endfor %}</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!!!!!
Simon

Comment: I don't think that it is possible this way - why don't you want to use `<table></table>`? It would be much easier to achieve then

Comment: That's true, but I thought I will encounter the same problem somewhen else.  I thought it might be possible to set the div's only on the first loop and put the rest into it.

Comment: Of course you can but you must remember that then you will get a serie of enclosed divs - it could be ok if they would have class `col-xs-4` and sum up to 12 (because divs creating one column would always be under another of same type) - anyway for me it does not deserve your time. Use `<table>` - this is why this tag exists ;)

Comment: Why can't you include the divs inside the loop exactly? I don't understand what you gain by removing them

Comment: Because then then they will be created in everlopy, means I got multiple div's which I don't like to have. Thanks @m.antkowicz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building a table out of divs. Use a table instead.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Shots</th>
        <th>Goals against</th>
    </tr>
    {% for t in teams %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ t.league_position }}</td>
        <td>{{ t.team_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ t.league_points }}</td>
        <td>{{ t.goals_shot }}</td>
        <td>{{ t.goals_received }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: It's not what I was exactly looking for, but for this certain case it fits good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include the divs then the only way possible would be to do an ajax request to populate the columns separately...

Below is untested (and probably wrong) but it should give an idea of what I mean

```
$.get('my_get_teams_url', function(data){
    for(i = 0; i < data.teams.length; i++)
    {
        $('#position').append(data.teams[i].position);
        $('#name').append(data.teams[i].name);
    } 
});
```